# String lists / Python

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I need to look for an item in a nested list and compare a string with it, but it keeps ignoring my code.

```
def add_new_car(brand,horse_power,car_list):
    for i in range(len(car_list)):
        if(car_list[i][0]==brand):
            car_list[i][1]=car_list[i][1]+1
        else:
            car_list=car_list+[[brand,1,False,horse_power]]
            break
```

My if condition does not work. The else condition works properly. I mean it goes into else condition even if `car_list[i][0]==brand`.

```
car_list=[['BMW',4,False,200],
          ['Mercedes',3,False,250],
          ['Renault',2,False,150],‌
          ​['Audi',3,False,180]]
```

When i try to call the function `add_new_car("BMW",car_list)` it adds a new list to my original list but it should make it `car_list=[['BMW',5,False,200],['Mercedes',3,False,250],['Renault',2,False,150],‌​['Audi',3,False,180]]`

Comment: Well, if `car_list[i][0]==brand` were actually true, that would work. Without seeing `car_list` or `brand`, we have no way to help you.

Comment: `car_list=[['BMW',4,False,200],['Mercedes',3,False,250],['Renault',2,False,150],['Audi',3,False,180]]` is my list.
When i try to call the function `car_list("BMW",car_list)" it adds a new list to my original list but it should make it `car_list=[['BMW',5,False,200],['Mercedes',3,False,250],['Renault',2,False,150],['Audi',3,False,180]]`

Comment: Add it to your main post.

Comment: What is the function `car_list` ?

Comment: it's add_new_car. I've corrected it.

Comment: `add_new_car` requires 3 arguments. What about `horse_power`?

Comment: strongly recommend using a different data structure for this, btw. If you want a list, consider a list of tuples `(brand, False, horsepower)` (what's the `False` for btw?) and duplicating cars. This is a great use case for a `collections.namedtuple` as well. Also strongly consider using a database for this -- sqlite is built-in and can be built in-memory if necessary.

Comment: This is my homework for my python class and i need to use the things that i learned in class so far. False is about a differen function i need to code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `for/break/else` construction

```
def add_new_car(brand, horse_power, car_list):
    for x in car_list:
        if x[0] == brand:
            x[1] += 1
            break
    else:
        # run if not break
        #car_list += [[brand, 1, False, horse_power]]
        car_list.append([brand, 1, False, horse_power]) #  Adam Smith suggestion

car_list = [
    ['BMW',4,False,200],
    ['Mercedes',3,False,250],
    ['Renault',2,False,150],
    ['Audi',3,False,180]
]

print car_list

add_new_car('Mercedes', 123, car_list)

print car_list
```

Comment: `car_list.append([brand, 1, False, horse_power])` is probably more clear, but YMMV

Comment: @AdamSmith you are right. I focused on `for/break/else` and I didn't notice this :)

Comment: Thank you! my code is now working as it should be. And i will consider Adam Smith's suggestion either. Thank you very much again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should call your function with the function name like this: `add_new_car("BMW",horse_power,car_list)` insert horse power there. also the `else` of the `if` statement is incorrect. as it always breaks out of the loop if it doesnt find your car in the first index. remove the entire `else` section and add `car_list.append([brand,1,False,horse_power])` outside of the loop at the end of the function. best of luck!

Comment: I'm aware of that i just miss write it there so add_new_car("BMW",200,car_list) does not work too.